# Где в Android studio находится R.java и все id

Tags: android-studio, java

Где в Android studio находится R.java?
Или же где в Android studio находятся все ID?

Answer (score 1):

Там же где и в Eclipse, в папке gen

Comment: Что-то я его там не обнаружил

Comment: Так может нужно сделать Rebuild? Если его там нет, то у вас ошибка в проекте, скорее всего в xml.

Comment: Делал я и Build и ReBuild. Папки gen нет тоже.

Comment: Нашёл какой-то аж вот где: \AndroidStudioProjects\ViewByIdProject\ViewById\build\source\r\debug\ru\startandroid\develop\viewbyid\R.java

там довольно много всего, хотя проект у меня состоит, можно сказать, из одной кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Переходите в каталог **Packages** --> **Имя вашего пакета** (например ru.test.app) --> **R.java**

Answer (score 1):

Попалась возможно связанная проблема: Android Studio в какой-то момент перестал распознавать класс *R* в файлах проекта (ничего никуда не перемещалось и не удалялось). Например, в *MyActivity.java*.

Как сказано ранее, помог *rebuild*.

Сам файл *R.java* создаётся в каталоге проектов по адресу типа:

> ...\AndroidProjects\YourAppName\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\ru\your_company_name\myapplication\R.java